Why does pressure drop with temperature in the atmosphere?
I am looking at altimeters in pilot training.
I understand why pressure drops with temperature in a constant volume ($pV=nRT$). But I don't understand why this is also true in the atmosphere. The volume in any given section of atmosphere need not be constant. It seems to me that as air cools and becomes more dense, it should take up less volume, i.e. be compressed by the air above it, and that the pressure should remain roughly constant, related only to the weight of the air column above it out to space, which shouldn't change much.
Another way to model it would be a 1-in-2 cylinder of air with a $14.7\,\text{lb}$ piston sitting on it. As I change the temperature, the piston will move up and down, but the pressure should stabilize at $14.7\,\text{psi}$.
My best guess is that I am modelling this in my head as a quasi-static system, and that the atmosphere is actually very dynamic.
Any help is much appreciated.
EDIT 1/1/25:
To clarify, I am not confused by the dropoff of pressure or temperature as a function of altitude--i.e., the standard atmosphere. I am confused by the statement that if you fly level from warm to cold, your altimeter reading falsely rises--i.e. the pressure measured by the altimeter drops. This is equivalent to stating that cold air is lower pressure than hot air. This question is answered at an operator level on many pilot resources, but I would like a physical understanding of it.


Why does pressure drop with temperature in the atmosphere?

I would not say that pressure drops with temperature, but rather that pressure and temperature both drop with altitude.  In fact, only pressure monotonically drops with altitude (for reasons I think you're familiar with) whereas temperature generally decreases with altitude in the lower atmosphere, but eventually, in the stratosphere, begins to increase.
I will take your question, then, to boil down to "Why does temperature decrease with height in the troposphere?"
The reason is that when air expands, it cools, and when it is compressed, it warms.  If you have vertical motions of air due to wind blowing across mountains or whatever, air that moves upward experiences lower pressure and so expands and gets colder, while air that moves downward contracts and gets warmer.  This happens without any heat transfer (so it is called "adiabatic warming/cooling").  Work done on a gas by its surroundings as it is compressed goes into its internal energy, increasing its temperature.
If you're in a part of the atmosphere that is well mixed due to turbulent motions, the temperature decrease with height is entirely explained by this adiabatic cooling. The temperature profile in such an area is described as the "adiabatic lapse rate".


It seems to me that as air cools and becomes more dense, it should take up less volume, i.e. be compressed by the air above it, and that the pressure should remain roughly constant, related only to the weight of the air column above it out to space, which shouldn't change much.

Even though the atmosphere goes very high, when in a fairly low-flying aircraft, you might be above a significant amount of the mass in a column of air.
Imagine you are at a particular altitude, say 6000 feet.   The altimeter is reading a pressure that is based on the mass of the air above you.
If you warm the air, it expands and now more of mass of that column is above you than it was before.   The altimeter at that altitude reads a higher pressure which it displays as a lower altitude.
A different way to think about it:
The altimeter will read 6000 feet when a certain mass of air is above it.   On a warm day, that mass will be higher up.   On a cold day, that mass will be closer to the ground.   So the point where the altimeter indicates 6000 feet will be higher up on a warm day and lower down on a cold day.

Just to restate your answer in my terms, the atmosphere bulges over high temperature/pressure areas and dents in over low temperature/pressure areas?
